# How to disable an eventListener in RCP?

Tags: eclipse, listener, rcp

I've an EventListener dedicated to listen to the focusLost() event of a Text in my view  in Eclipse RCP. The Listener's working fine. But at some point of the execution I want to disable this Listener from Listening to the Text and Later I wish it to be activated.
How can it be deactivated or activated as per our needs programatically ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `removeListener()` method of [SWT Widget](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Widget.html). You will need a reference to the `Listener` to do this.

This reference can be obtained using the `getListeners(int eventType)` method. 

The event types are defined as constants in the [SWT class](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/Widget.html). It could look like this, I'm not sure about the actual event type though

```
Listener[] focusOutListeners = myWidget.getListeners(SWT.FocusOut); 

for(int i = 0 ; i< focusOutListeners; i++){
    myWidget.removeListener(SWT.FocusOut, focusOutListeners[i]);
}

// ... do stuff the listeners will not know about ...//

for(int i = 0 ; i< focusOutListeners; i++){
    myWidget.addListener(SWT.FocusOut, focusOutListeners[i]);
}
```

AFAIK there is no other means in SWT to disable a `Listener`, but as your `Listener` just implements the according interface, you can implement custom disable/enable methods. Then your code could look like this:
Listener[] focusOutListeners = myWidget.getListeners(SWT.FocusOut);

```
for(int i = 0 ; i< focusOutListeners; i++){
    CustomListener listener = (CustomListener)focusOutListeners[i]);
    listener.disable();
}

// ... do stuff the listeners will not know about ...//

for(int i = 0 ; i< focusOutListeners; i++){
    CustomListener listener = (CustomListener)focusOutListeners[i]);
    listener.enable();
}
```

The action under the hood is described nicely in Paul Webster's answer.

Comment: Thank you Kostja for your answer. Could you pls show me a sample how to make a reference to the listener ?

Comment: Thank you kostja very much. finally i got the point. Thank you again

Answer (score 0):

The other common pattern used is to include a boolean with the listener (or associated with the text field).  While probably not too costly on a single widget, adding and removing listeners potentially involves array copies and allocations.  Just set enabled to false:

```
public final void handleEvent(final Event event) {
    if (!textListenerEnabled) {
        return;
    }
    // the rest of your processing.
}
```

Comment: Thank you Paul for the answer. Your idea is also great and amazing.